# How many bit strings of length eight contain either three consecutive $0'$s or four consecutive $1'$s?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many bit strings of length eight contain either three consecutive $0'$s or four consecutive $1'$s?

> $$2^5 + 2^4 + 2^4 + 2^4 + 2^4 + 2^4 + 2^4 + 2^4$$
>
> $$2^4 + 2^3 + 2^3 + 2^3 + 2^3 + 2^3 + 2^3$$

take the first line plus the second line minus $5!$

Would this be the correct answer, if not why?

Comment: um.. the first line is 112, the second line is 48
112 + 48 - 5! is 40 which is not > 256

Comment: It would help if you provided an explanation of what those numbers are.

Comment: No, it should start 0, 0, 1, 4...

Comment: I certainly interpret "0000" as having three consecutive 0s.